# JavaScript only run operation if the operation result is < 100

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators, operation

How can I run in JavaScript a operation, ONLY if the operation result is < 100, as an example.

I tried the following code but the += operation got executed twice, but I only want it to be executed after the if statement.

```
let progress = 0

function earn(howmuch) {
    if (progress += howmuch < 100) {
        console.log(progress) // console.logs 1
        progress += howmuch
        console.log(progress) // console.logs 2
    }
}

document.querySelector('.click-area').addEventListener('click', function() {
    earn(1)
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: The `+=` operator is the combination of addition (`+`) and assignment (`=`). You don't want the assignment part in your `if` condition: `(progress += howmuch < 100)` -> `((progress + howmuch) < 100)`

Comment: Thank you now it works. Actually it makes sense but I didn't think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` is an assignment.

In your case the increase happens in the condition check and inside if.

You should change the `+=` in the condition to be `+`, that way the value won't be changed, just temporary calculated

Answer (score 1):

You must do the calculation of your variable outside the conditional so that it is compared as you want.

Here you have an example:

```js
let progress = 0;

function earn(howmuch) {
    let new_progress = progress + howmuch;
    if (new_progress < 100) { // Here you had the problem
        progress = new_progress;
        console.log(progress); // console.logs 1
    }
}

document.querySelector('.click-area').addEventListener('click', function() {
    earn(1)
});
```

```html
<button class="click-area">Click</button>
```

In your case, you made the assignment `+=` within the conditional, and this did not have an effect until the next line.

Doing the calculation in the line before the conditional, solve the problem.

Comment: I have modified my answer